# Core Data Model stuck on logo after discarding changes

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data

I was having some issues where my app was crashing due to not being able to locate my model. To fix the issue I reverted back to my last committed change using "Discard Changes in Selected Files…" on my .xcdatamodeld file.

After doing this I am now stuck seeing a Core Data logo instead of the model editor. Clearing my project and quitting Xcode has not helped. What can I do?

What I'm seeing in the editor:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I viewed the contents of the .xcdatamodeld and opened the .xcdatamodel file in there I was able to view it again. To incorporate it back into my project however I just ended up deleting the file then re-creating it.